# Получить поля объекта в массиве php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив. Каждый элемент массива представляет собой объект с двумя полями.
Пример

```
[{"type": "photo", "photo": {photo}}, {"type": "audio", "audio": {audio}}]
```

**Как мне из этого получить поля объектов: type и photo (или audio, без разницы)?**

$a['type'] не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так:

```
$obj_array = json_decode('[{"type": "photo", "photo": {"some": "content"}}, {"type": "audio", "audio": {"some": "content"}}]');
print_r($obj_array);
$reult = array();
    foreach($obj_array as $obj) {
        $type = $obj->type;
        $reult[$obj->type] = $obj->$type;
    }

print_r($reult);
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => photo
            [photo] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [some] => content
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => audio
            [audio] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [some] => content
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [photo] => stdClass Object
        (
            [some] => content
        )

    [audio] => stdClass Object
        (
            [some] => content
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы привели строку просто для демонстрации?
Вообще к свойствам объекта обращаются так:

```
$a->type
```

Соответственно из массива

```
$ar[0]->type
```

Comment: Если строка не для демонстрации, а в таком виде (в виде строки) получаете массив откуда либо.  То сначала вам нужно воспользоваться   json_decode