# Вывод из массива

Tags: php, массивы

есть массив

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [MIGX_id] => 1
                [country] => Россия
                [description] => 
                [image] => 
                [ogran] => 
                [zach] => 
                [commisse] => 
            )

)
```

где ошибся? не выводит

```
foreach ($data as $val){
   echo $val['country'];
}
```

Comment: std это структура объекта, так и обращайтесь к нему как почитается (как к объекту)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас массив с объектом
[Схожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649640/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-php)
Используйте

```
echo $val->country;
```